# Hyperlinks(to external URLs) in Bluebeam Studio PDFs

Tags: api, pdf, adobe

I’m able to export PDFs from a third party to a Bluebeam project in Bluebeam's Studio via their API. However, the PDF has hyperlinks which if clicked should prompt a user’s browser to open a page in the third party’s website. This is the default behaviour in PDF viewers such as Adobe however I’m unable to reproduce the same functionality within the Bluebeam PDF reader (inside studio).
Is there a way to achieve this?

TL;DR
I want the ability to click hyperlinks within a PDF in a Bluebeam Studio project and open that link in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with **Revu 2018, Update 2**. Upgrading to **Revu 2018, Update 3** solved the issue for me. Hope this helps some other fellow.